# I successfully installed numpy using pip 21.1.1 but python is not importing it

Tags: python

I successfully installed `numpy` module using `pip 21.1.1` but python is not able to import it. My python version is `Python 3.8.5` and the following image represents my error:

[image: Error]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

try using the follow line:

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

after that just try again with your line

```
python -c 'import numpy'
```

that should resolve the problem